# Set oldstylenums as the default writing style throughout the document

Tags: thesis, oldstylenums

I am trying to set all numbers in my document in \oldstylenums format. There are about 345 instances where the numbers need to be changes to oldstylenums in the text.
Is it possible to convert them into the format of choice? Is it possible exclude tables from this command?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[alsoload=synchem]{siunitx}  

\begin{document}

Around 72~{\milli\liter} of peroxide was added to the 25 samples and allowed to rest for \SI{32}{\day}

The results were:

\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
  123 & 234 & 345 \\
  456 & 567 & 678 \\
  789 & 890 & 900 \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Note: I've used both styles of writing with and without \SI{} as I want to see if oldstylenums can be used when number are wrapped in this function.

Comment: Maybe try with the `cfr-lm` package (requires the T1 font encoding).

Comment: Which main (text) font do you employ?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is `alsoload=synchem` used for here? (According to the `siunitx` manual, `alsoload` is ignored by version 2)

Comment: @leandriis It is used to get micromol and other chemistry symbols.

Comment: @Mico the default. I do not specify a additional maintext font

Comment: In that case, just follow @leandriis's advice to load the `cfr-lm` package.